# CakePhp debug/var_dump styling

Tags: debugging, cakephp, var-dump

This may be a simple question for those more adept at CakePHP than me BUT:

I have two environments [work and home], which I've been using github to work between.

If I run a var_dump() on my work machine, the resultant dump is a CakePHP formatted HTML list. It's great for debugging.

If I run var_dump() at home on the same code at home, I'm presented with a more traditional list: formatted with whitespace, but not in HTML.

I'm pretty sure this is a setting somewhere, but I do not know where it is - all the documentation online seems to point to the debug() function, which I actually find a little less useful.

Does anyone know about this?
Thanks in advance.
Rick

Comment: Try view source from your browser and ensure you get all css file mentioned on header tag.

Comment: `css/cake.generic.css` is correctly included, so I don't think it's missing anything.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, try dump_r.php (php 5.3+)

demo: http://o-0.me/dump_r/
repo: https://github.com/leeoniya/dump_r.php

also installable via Composer
*require: "leeoniya/dump-r": "dev-master"*
https://packagist.org/packages/leeoniya/dump-r

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy way: on your home machine, you click 'view source' and you'll see nicely formatted var_dump() output there.

Wei

Answer (score 0):

Why not using debug() instead var_dump()?

- Are you using xdebug on both machines?
- Is the php version the same on both machines?
- Same php.ini settings for xdebug and error level?

Comment: Because debug lets me inspect objects nicely [at least when the layout is functioning]. Besides... I prefer it.
I want to fix the behaviour, not sidestep it.